# How to add function for output screen?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, primes

I wrote a "how to Find Prime Numbers" code. I used "For loops" but now I want to use function (def). I don't want to use the function for whole code, I just only want to use the function for print my answer part, where it says "prime" or "not a Prime". If any one knows how to do it, please tell me. Thanks and I here is my code.

```
ASK = int (input("YOUR NUMBER:"))

for i in range (2,ASK):
    m= ASK%i
    print (ASK, "MOD", i , "=", m)
    if (m == 0):
        break  

    if(m>0):
        print ("Prime Number")
    else:
        print ("Not Prime Number")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for.

Is the aim of the program to check each number in the range to see if it is prime? Or have I completely misunderstood?

```
def myprint(x):
    if x > 0:
        print "prime"
    else:
        print "not prime"

ASK = int (input("YOUR NUMBER:")) 

for i in range (2,ASK): 
    m= ASK%i 
    print (ASK, "MOD", i , "=", m) 
    if (m == 0): 
        break
    myprint(m)
```

Comment: Hi Brinded, thanks for the Help. I tried to move some lines to the function and the program works but it does not show rather it is "Prime or not"  Here is the code:                                                                                                                  def myprint(m):
    if m > 0:
        print ("YES! It is a Prime Number \n")
        print (ASK, "MOD", i , "=", m)
    else:
        print ("not prime")
        return;
    
    
ASK = int (input("YOUR NUMBER:")) 

for i in range (2,ASK): 
    m= ASK%i 
    if (m == 0): 
        break
    myprint(m)

Comment: Think about how the a function works. I deliberately used 'x' in my def to try and show you. 
When you define the function you tell it how many arguments to expect. In my example it expects 1. 
These arguments are not global variables in the definition (ie they do not correspond directly to variables in the code). When we call the function we tell the program 'use the variable m in this function' at this point it will know the value of m. 
In your code the function does not know what ASK or i means.

Answer (score 0):

```
`def print_prime(m):
   if(m>0):
     print ("Prime Number")
   else:
     print ("Not Prime Number")
 print_prime(m)`
```

I think this is what you need. Google, "Functions in python".